# Intellij 14 can't checkout subversion

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Since the update from Intellij 13 to Intellij 14, I can't make a checkout with subversion, since I can browse the repository.
I received this message:

> Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "..."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I'd got the same error before under Intellij 13 and the solution was to uncheck the `Use command line client` option in `File/Settings/Version Control/Subversion`. So I verify this parameter but it was already uncheck.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 13):

To resolve this I:

- Open the settings here `File/Settings/Version Control/Subversion`
- Check the option `Use command line client`.
- Close the panel.
- Have a new warning from IntelliJ about the use of subversion with command line.
- Reopen the settings here `File/Settings/Version Control/Subversion`
- Uncheck the option "Use command line client".
- Close the panel.
- Try the checkout...

... and then it worked.
I think it was a default parameter in the configuration out there.

Comment: In my case, I had the "Use command client" checkbox already checked.  I unchecked it and tried the checkout again.  After logging into SVN, I was able to check code out.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me after updating. There appears to be 2 settings for this - one in an active project and one in the default "Welcome to IntelliJ IDEA" screen.

To fix it click:

1. "Configure" with a gear icon in the bottom right.
2. "Settings" from the popup
3. "Version Control" from the list on the left
4. "Subversion" and then there is a check box next to "Use command line client"

This check box is different from the one in File > Settings so unchecking this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:
Studio-> Settings->Subversion-> Uncheck "Use command-line client".